# copy and reference in Swift

Tags: swift, reference, copy

I know that struct, array, dictionary... in Swift are passed by value and class are passed by reference. But in below code, is it still referenced for constant arrays?

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3]
let arr2 = arr1
```

Another question, Swift will copy an array only if you modify it?

```
var anotherArray1 = [1,2,3]
var anotherArray2 = anotherArray1 // anotherArray1 and anotherArray2 reference the the same array 
anotherArray2[0] = 10 //Swift will copy values in anotherArray1 into anotherArray2 then changing value at 0 index to 10
```

Comment: For your second question: http://natecook.com/blog/2014/06/swift-array-copying-ambiguity/

Comment: Look for "Copy-on-Write" in the answer to the referenced thread.